# save array of data URIs with fileReader javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, filereader

i have an input with multiples images inside, that is, i have this:

```
input id="imagen" onchange="trans()" type="file" name="imgs" multiple="true" class="form-control required" >
```

I want the trans function to save an array with the data uris inside it, so that each image has its corresponding representation in the array, however, my script has problems saving it and I do not know why.

```
 function trans(v) {
        blobs=new Array();
        var file    = document.querySelector('#imagen').files;
        for (i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
            reader  = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file[i]);
            reader.onloadend = function () {
            blobs[i]=reader.result;
            };

        }
        console.log(blobs[0]);//this not is working
            };
```

EDIT: for the answer in the comment, i tried this:

```
var blobs=[];
    function onload(i) {
        return function() {  blobs[i]=reader.result; };
    }
    function trans(v) {

        var file    = document.querySelector('#imagen').files;
        for (i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
            reader  = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file[i]);
            reader.onloadend = onload(i);

        }
        console.log(blobs[0]);//this not is working
    };
```

Did not work, what is wrong?

Comment: `onloadend` is asynchronous...so `i` will be at it's maximum by the time it triggers. Need a closure as per duplicate link above. Also can't log `blobs` until they have all loaded. Suggest using a promise array